# I forgot to deliver tutorials

Tags: teaching, time-management, tutoring

I feel like I have made a massive mistake of my career. I do tutorials for three subjects and although we are almost end of the first trimester but one of the module just started last week and I supposed to do the second week's tutorial today for that module.

This morning I felt sick and i had constant headache. Even though I went in University and I did one of my other tutorials but I completely forgot to deliver tutorials for the module which started last week. I realised that I missed them after two hours. I never felt that much disappointed in my entire life.

I have Phd submission soon and the fact I was not feeling well today seems to be the major cause and I also completely forgot to organise my calendar for this week.

Well it has happened now and I have informed the course coordinator. I didn't hear back from her yet.

But my question is how today's mistake can affect my job? What likely consequences I will face? How should I handle this mistake? And finally, will they judge my previous performance based on this mistake?

Cheers

Comment: As much as I sympathise with your feelings, I don't think the question is answerable in this form. We don't know your contractual obligations, or what are the customs in your Department, and how badly this can affect your job.

Comment: Can you just rearrange the tutorial you missed? That would seem the simplest solution. It might be a faff if a lot of people are involved, but it's probably doable.

Comment: I don't know what delivering a tutorial means, but if you have the email addresses of the people who were counting on you, perhaps you could email them all, using the bcc field.  If you do, keep it succinct.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Yes this eventually I will do. So next week I will cover two topics. But the biggest fear I am going through is to face likely consequences, especially on my reputation.

Comment: @aparente001 After the lecture students take one hour session to do some practical work and engagement base activities mainly to learn further on the topic that was discussed in the lecture. I just do tutorials. I have emailed course lecturer and I will meet her next week. Cheers as your comment helped me to write a succinct email than a long.

Comment: @Ahmad - It's okay.  You're human.  Just try not to let it happen again.  Glad to hear you are conscientious about your teaching duties.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you started rectifying the mistake by informing the coordinator. I would apologize sincerely and offer to to deliver the tutorial at another time. Mistakes happen and you are only a human and you were sick and that is understandable. Also, make sure not to miss any other tutorials in the future.

Comment: Hi Thanks- this instantly helped to cop with the pressure i felt. Of course, it was a lesson learned.